# Leaflet map appearing in editor, but not on site

Tags: javascript, html, css, leaflet

I'm currently using Atom with a live preview extension, which accurately shows what my page is *supposed* to look like. That said, when I go to the actual site, I see the header only, not the map. Not sure what's going on. I've tried CTRL-F5 and reloading the page with no effect. Here's what I've got.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Map Prototype</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.css" />
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.3.7/sandstone/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-G3G7OsJCbOk1USkOY4RfeX1z27YaWrZ1YuaQ5tbuawed9IoreRDpWpTkZLXQfPm3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapse" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">...</button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Map Demo</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://vietnamwarstories.indiana.edu/" target="_blank">Website</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://vietnamwarstories.indiana.edu/contact/" target="_blank">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right"></ul>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div id="map-container">
      <div id="map"></div>
    </div>

    <script src="js/map.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**index.css**

```
html, body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#map-container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

**map.js**

```
var map = L.map ('map', { center: [16.056, 100.745], zoom: 6 });

L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);
```

Comment: Deleting #map-container and setting #map to a fixed size (width: 960px;
height: 500px;) instead, and it worked... but ideally I'd like for the size to be scalable.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it by just deleting the #map-container div and setting html and body to 100%, and map to 100%.

```
html, body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

#map {
  height: 100%;
}
```